# Minimize the objective function for K-means clustering

Tags: calculus

Let $$x_1,...,x_n ⊂ R^D.$$ Let $$F : R^D → [0,∞)$$ be
$$F(y)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} ∥x_i −y∥_2^2.$$
Prove that F is minimized for $y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i.$

So we have the euclidean metric, hence
$$F(y)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{D}(x_{i_j} −y)^2 \rightarrow min.$$ Finding the derivative and setting it equal to 0 will give us:
$$F(y)= 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{D}(x_{i_j} −y)=0.$$ 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y)=0.$$
$$y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is totally fine. You're supposed to take the "average" of all of the vectors, what you've derived is the standard k-means formula here :)